# REST. Один GET запрос для разных ролей

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, rest, asp.net-web-api, валидация

Есть три роли: `admin`, `area`(оператор района) и `school`(оператор школы).

Имена `area-пользователей` совпадают с `Id` из таблицы `Area` базы данных.
Имена `school-пользователей` совпадают с `Id` из таблицы `School` базы данных.

`area-пользователи` должны иметь доступ только к студентам своего района, т.е. имя `area-пользователя` и `StudentDto.AreaId` должны совпадать. `school-пользователи` должны иметь доступ только к студентам своей школы, т.е. имя `school-пользователя` и `StudentDto.SchoolId` должны совпадать.

А теперь код:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AreaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
}    

public class Area
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
}

public interface IStudentService
{
    IEnumerable<StudentDto> GetAll(int? areaId, int? schoolId);
}

[RoutePrefix("api/students")]        
public class StudentsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IStudentService _studentService;

    public StudentsController(IStudentService studentService)
    {
        _studentService = studentService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll(int? areaId, int? schoolId)
    {
        var studentDtos = _studentService.GetAll(areaId: areaId, schoolId: schoolId);
        var authorizedUser = User.Identity.Name;

        if (User.IsInRole("school"))    
        {
            if (!studentDtos.All(dto => dto.SchoolId.ToString() == authorizedUser))
            {
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("area"))
        {
            if (!studentDtos.All(dto => dto.AreaId.ToString() == authorizedUser))
            {
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
        }

        return Ok(studentDtos);
    }
}
```

---

### Вопрос

Хочется чтобы URI получения списка студентов для всех трех типов пользователей был одинаков `GET: .../api/students`, **как я понимаю так и должно быть согласно REST** (*если это не так, то подправьте*).

Насколько правильно все сделал я в выше описанном коде, не слишком ли нагружен метод контроллера? **В частности интересует, что говорит "хорошая практика" о том как выполнена валидация?**

Я также рассматривал вариант создания кастомного атрибута (фильтр) или создание отдельных URI для каждого типа пользователя, типа: `api/students/admin`, `api/students/area`, `api/students/school`. С кастомным атрибутом я так и не разобрался, т.к. на входе нельзя валидировать список студентов - ведь его сначала надо получить *(или ничего страшного если получение организовать в самом фильтре?)*. А касаемо отдельных URI, то как писал выше, то это уже не REST.

Answer (score 1):

```
GET: .../api/students
```

Да, это соответствует *REST naming guidelines*

Если быть точнее то вам надо таки писать:

```
GET: .../api/students?role=school
```

В параметрах принято указывать фильтрацию, роль коей у вас выполняют ваши роли.

Comment: А зачем в строке запроса указывать роль, ведь я и так ее узнаю через `User.IsInRole()`?

Comment: Да, верно, можно и так